# Two elements absolutely positioned at the same place but not showing at the same place

Tags: html, css, css-position, background-image

So, I have these two things. One is a transparent button and the other one is an image behind it.

I did that because adding a background didn't work. Here's what I tried:

```
.top-container > button {
    background-image: url(path-to-image); /* I also tried image() */
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    width: 100px;
    height: 33px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'CapitalisTypOasis', 'CapitalisTypOasisMedium';
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.7em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I did all of the tiny variations I could think of, and since my deadline is soon, I put an image behind the button. Works perfectly.

```
.boutonsim { 
    display: block;
    height: 33px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.7em;
    z-index: 1;
}

.top-container > button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 33px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'CapitalisTypOasis', 'CapitalisTypOasisMedium';
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.7em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top-container">
            <img id="img2" src="images/haut.png" />
            <img id="title" src="images/nom.png" />
            <img id="logo" src="images/LOGO.png" />
            <div class="boutonsim" style="right: 80px;"><img src="images/clipart/boutonORIGINAL.png" /></div>
            <button style="right: 80px;">Culture</button>

        </div>
```

They're supposed to be at the same place but when I open my file in Chrome, they're not.
Could anyone help? Thanks.

This is a GIF of the result in a snippet if it can help:

```html
<a href="https://gyazo.com/c849e62e7893453a2b442f2060bce1e4"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/c849e62e7893453a2b442f2060bce1e4.gif" alt="Image from Gyazo" width="166"/></a>
```

Comment: Can you provide your html as well?

Comment: You probably don't need two buttons, try to figure out if you problem could be solved if you had one button.

Comment: @Kosh I tried and itsnot possible to have my button with a background image idk why it just ignores it.

Comment: @John i edited the post.

Comment: @manouna, so your actual question should be `I cannot apply background image to <button>`. Otherwise this is [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Kosh I gave up on adding one because it didn't work even with technially correct solutions and my deadline is soon.

Comment: @manouna, Could you please share your technically correct solutions which did not work? At least one of them? Probably someone might point out what was wrong.

Comment: @Kosh done. For the moment my solution works but if someone makes it work the right way well good

Comment: @manouna, you're almost there, but there are 3 possible issues: 1. you did not specified `background-size` property -- if the image is larger than your button it won't fit correctly. 2. path to the image may be incorrect (you can check it in console, it will throw an error). 3. the image may be broken and does not display correctly (to check this, you might replace the image with another one). [This may help too](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Comment: @Kosh I drew the images myself I made them the exact size of the button and they work when used in img src tags. There also isn't any path error since there's only 1 folder. It's really weird why it doesn't work I have no idea what to do I gotta finish this for today.

Comment: @manouna, I could help you better if I knew more details on your actual setup. All I can do now -- just guess =)) Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR;* position them with anything but `em`.

The button must have a different `font-size` than the rest of the dom (which is also default behaviour), which means that the `div` and the `button` have different `font-size`s. So because you are positioning them with `em`, they will be positioned differently (div: 27.2px and button: 22.667px), since the CSS compiler looks at the elements `font-size` to determine the top value in `px`.

Comment: Good. If the answer works for you please accept it as the answer to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to apply a `background` image to your button (I believe it's your *real* problem).

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 33px;
  padding: 0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1019/100/33) no-repeat;
  color: white;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Culture</button>
```

Comment: Hi, the reason I did my weird thing is that this does not work with me. I tried doing that first and nothing showed up so I used this eeh-crafty method.